# Better solution to remove special character from string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function

I have a table with 450,000 model names. I need to strip off special characters from model names and write it to a new column in the table.

1. I have a function to replace all model names with modelname as input parameter and returns clean model name.
2. Procedure calls the function above with model name.

The problem is It takes around 1 hr 40 minutes to go through 50,000 records. At this rate it would take forever to complete this process! Is there any better way to do this? Replace would have been a better solution but I dont have entire list of special characters!

```
Function 

[dbo].[RemoveSpecialCharaters] (@model nvarchar(255))
Returns nvarchar(255)

as
    BEGIN

    Declare @search varchar(50)

    SET @search ='%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'

    while PATINDEX(@search,@model) > 0
        BEGIN
        set @model = STUFF(@model,PatIndex(@search,@model),1,'')
        END

    Return @model
    END
```

Comment: Can you post the `Function` which you are using to remove `special characters`

Comment: How are you "going though" your records? Do you use a cursor or a plain update statement? What DBMS is this (Oracle, SqlServer, ...). Please add those details to your question.

Comment: @NoDisplayName Added the function to the main post.

Comment: @HansKesting  Oops! Updated it is SQL server 2008. I am using a cursor to get model names and pass it on to the function. Basically calling function for every modelname!

Comment: How would `UPDATE thetable SET newmodelname = dbo.RemoveSpecialCharaters(oldmodelname)` perform, compared to the cursor? Maybe check on a limited set first. Although I'm not sure it would be possible to update all 450.000 rows in one transaction.

Comment: @HansKesting the perfomance was the same. The list was really long and I had to use cursor to fetch each modelname. It took around 7 hours! But it did complete with the result as desired! Guess that is the only way.